# visual studio express complains missing ';' after type in c program

Tags: c

What is the problem with my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;

    char string[32] = "Teste de solução";

    file = fopen("C:\file.txt", "w");

    printf("Digite um texto para gravar no arquivo: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        putc(string[i], file);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\guilherme\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\helloworld\helloworld\hello.c(14): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evidently you are compiling this as C, not C++.  VS doesn't support C99, in which case you may not do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
```

You need to do this instead:

```
int i;

...

for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
```

Where the declaration of `i` must come before all statements in the function.

Comment: same problem now in the line "int i;"

Answer (score 2):

I think Oli Charlesworth has given you the answer you need.

Here are some tips for you:

- If you use a backslash inside a string, you must put two backslashes.
- You should check the result of `fopen()`, and if it is `NULL` you should stop with an error.
- You should not specify the size of the array for your string; let the compiler count how many characters to allocate.
- In the `for` loop, you should not hard-code the size of the string; use `sizeof()` and let the compiler check the length, or else loop until you see the terminating nul byte.  I suggest the latter.

Rewritten version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    int i;

    char string[] = "Teste de solução";

    file = fopen("C:\\tmp\\file.txt", "w");
    if (!file) {
        printf("error!\n");
    }

    printf("Digite um texto para gravar no arquivo: ");
    for(i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        putc(string[i], file);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```